# Backbone.Marionette extending region stops onClose() function from calling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've created a Backbone, Marionette and Require.js application and am now trying to add smooth transitioning between regions.

To do this easily* ive decided to extend the marionette code so it works across all my pages (theres a lot of pages so doing it manually would be too much)

Im extending the marionette.region open and close function. Problem is that it now doesnt call the onClose function inside each of my views.

If I add the code directly to the marionette file it works fine. So I'm probably merging the functions incorrectly, right?

Here is my code:

```
extendMarrionette: function () {
  _.extend(Marionette.Region.prototype, {

    open : function (view) {
      var that = this;

      // if this is the main content and should transition
      if (this.$el.attr("id") === "wrapper" && document.wrapperIsHidden === true) {
        this.$el.empty().append(view.el);
        $(document).trigger("WrapperContentChanged")

      } else if (this.$el.attr("id") === "wrapper" && document.wrapperIsHidden === false) {
        $(document).on("WrapperIsHidden:open", function () {

          //swap content
          that.$el.empty().append(view.el);

          //tell router to transition in
          $(document).trigger("WrapperContentChanged");

          //remove this event listener
          $(document).off("WrapperIsHidden:open", that);
        });

      } else {
        this.$el.empty().append(view.el);
      }

    },

    //A new function Ive added - was originally inside the close function below. Now the close function calls this function.
    kill : function (that) {
      var view = this.currentView;
      $(document).off("WrapperIsHidden:close", that)
      if (!view || view.isClosed) {
        return;
      }

      // call 'close' or 'remove', depending on which is found
      if (view.close) {
        view.close();
      }
      else if (view.remove) {
        view.remove();
      }

      Marionette.triggerMethod.call(that, "close", view);

      delete this.currentView;
    },

    // Close the current view, if there is one. If there is no
    // current view, it does nothing and returns immediately.
    close : function () {
      var view = this.currentView;
      var that = this;

      if (!view || view.isClosed) {
        return;
      }

      if (this.$el.attr("id") === "wrapper" && document.wrapperIsHidden === true) {
        this.kill(this);

      } else if (this.$el.attr("id") === "wrapper" && document.wrapperIsHidden === false) {

        //Browser bug fix - needs set time out
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(document).on("WrapperIsHidden:close", that.kill(that));
        }, 10)


      } else {
        this.kill(this);
      }

    }

  });
}
```

Comment: What version of Marionette are you using?

Comment: Im using V 1.8.3 - should probably do the upgrade to v2

Comment: Thanks. The `Region` code has changed a lot between the different versions ;-].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your issue is that you are not passing a function to your event listener, but instead calling the code directly in the code below.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(document).on("WrapperIsHidden:close", that.kill(that));
}, 10)
```

It is likely that you want something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(document).on("WrapperIsHidden:close", function (){ that.kill(that); });
}, 10)
```

Another possible problem is that you are mixing up your references to `this`/`that` in your `kill` function. It seems like you probably want `var view` to either be assigned to `that.view` or to use `this` rather than `that` throughout the method.

Answer to your additional problems:

You should try passing the `view` variable from the `close` function directly into your `kill` function because the reference to `currentView` is already changed to the new view object when you actually want to old view object. The reason this is happening is that you are setting a timeout before executing the `kill` function. You can see this if you look at the `show` source code. It expects `close`, `open` and then `currentView` assignment to happen synchronously in order.

Comment: Aah okay, i see I actually made some silly errors there with the this/that.

Made the fix, now it seems to be calling the onClose function on the view which we're navigating to rather than the view we're navigating away from.

Progress.

Comment: Dustin, added answer to you additional problems.

Comment: Np. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you extend the Marionette.Region? That way you can choose between using your custom Region class, or the original one if you don't need the smooth transition in all cases. (And you can always extend it again if you need some specific behavior for some specific case).

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#region-class

```
var MyRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({
    open: function() {
        //Your open function
    }

    kill: function() {
        //Your kill function
    }

    close: function() {
        //Your close function
    }
});

App.addRegions({
    navigationRegion: MyRegion
});
```

Comment: I really like the idea of this (would solve the need for doing a query on what region im on in the extended code), but correct me if I'm wrong - when adding a Region we actually select the css selector like so:

    App.addRegions({
        navigationRegion: "#navigation"
    });

Comment: Oh wait a minute (should hve read the link).. will give it a try as well